# Most intuitive way to register "commands" in an extensible IRC bot in Go

Tags: go

I'm writing an IRC bot as a toy project, and one of the goals is to be easy and straight-forward to implement and register new commands.

As I'm new to Go, I don't know which would be the "Go way" for doing it.

This is a working "hello world" command:

```
package example

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/fabioxgn/go-bot"
)

func hello(command *bot.Cmd) (msg string, err error) {
    msg = fmt.Sprintf("Hello %s", command.Nick)
    return
}

func init() {
    bot.RegisterCommand(&bot.CustomCommand{
        Cmd:         "hello",
        CmdFunc:     hello,
        Description: "Sends a 'Hello' message to you on the channel.",
    })
}
```

Would an interface make it easier for the user to figure out how to write a new command? In this case, instead of a struct with a `CmdFunc`, an interface like:

```
type CustomCommand interface {
    Cmd() string
    CmdFunc(cmd *Cmd) (string, error)
    Description() string
    Usage() string
}
```

Or maybe the `RegisterCommand` function receive several args, like this [Google example](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/source/browse/examples/main.go#81)?

```
func registerDemo(name, scope string, main func(c *http.Client, argv []string)) {
    if demoFunc[name] != nil {
        panic(name + " already registered")
    }
    demoFunc[name] = main
    demoScope[name] = scope
}
```

I personally don't like the interface idea. For me one of the best things about Go is the freedom you get to just implementa a little func and make magic happen, but I don't know what would be idiomatic Go and intuitive for the fellow Gophers. :)